# 'Not A Member of Object' Error

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I think I'm beginning to like this coding stuff. Anyway in my current Shooting Gallery project I have a JavaScript question. I'm building in Unity3d and I get a "transform" is not a member of "Object" error on the code inserted below.

```c#
var newball;
static var tempBasketBall :Rigidbody;
private var canFire = true;
var pos :Transform[];
var ball1 :Rigidbody;
var canControl1 = true;
var destroyTime :int = 6;
var player1 :GameObject;
var b1Parent :Transform;

var yVel :float;
var zVel :float;

function Start()
{
    ball1 = Instantiate (tempBasketBall, pos[0].position, pos[0].rotation);
    ball1.transform.parent = b1Parent;
}

function Update() { 
    if(Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
        animation.PlayQueued("fire", QueueMode.PlayNow);   
}

function TapFunction() {
    animation.PlayQueued("fire", QueueMode.PlayNow);
    player1.animation.PlayQueued("fire");
    ball1.transform.parent = null;
    ball1.useGravity = true;
    ball1.velocity = transform.TransformDirection(0, yVel, zVel);
    MakeBall1(pos[0]);
    canControl1 = false;
    player1.animation.PlayQueued("idle");
}

function MakeBall1(pos)
{
    yield new WaitForSeconds(1);
    ball1 = Instantiate(tempBasketBall, pos.transform.position, pos.transform.rotation);
    ball1.transform.parent = b1Parent;
    canControl1 = true;
}
```

The error is in the MakeBall function at the end. To my untrained mind, it seems I established the
transform in the start function. As usual any assistance and shared knowledge will be tremendously appreciated.

Comment: Meanwhile, are you saying the above is supposed to be JavaScript? Because it's invalid: variable declarations are not supposed to include a type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transform(you are passing as argument an onject of this tipe) does not have a "transform" member,you should use pos.position

Comment: Chitu  Thanks for your comment Bogdan. I am not a talented enough programmer to fully understand your answer. Can you write out an example of what you're suggesting.  I see pos.transform.position already in the Makeball1 function! Would an option be to create a transform member? If so, how would I write that code out?

Comment: That's the thing.In Makeball1 you can't have pos.transform.position.Just delete ".transform" and your code will compile.

Comment: Chitu  Ok, I hate to be a bother but, one last question. When I removed " transform" it gave an error that 'position was not a member of the object'. However when I added a '0' to the exposed Transform variable on line 4, the 'not a member' error went away. Now I get a     ....Assets/Scripts/NewBaller1.js(4,19): UCE0001: ';' expected. Insert a semicolon at the end...error. Clearly there already is a semicolon there. What's up with the redundancy?